# Are the Vikramaditya stories considered scripture?

Tags: scripture, vikramaditya

Wiki says:

> Vikramaditya (IAST: Vikramāditya) was a legendary emperor of ancient India. Often characterized as an ideal king, he is known for his generosity, courage, and patronage of scholars. Vikramaditya is featured in hundreds of traditional Indian legends, including those in Baital Pachisi and Singhasan Battisi. Many describe him as a universal ruler, with his capital at Ujjain (Pataliputra or Pratishthana in a few stories).

Are the Vetala and other stories connected with Vikramaditya considered scripture?

Comment: No. However they are supposed to be illustrations of righteousness and just capabilities of a real King. There are several source of truth besides scriptures.